# Getting $craftPath error on server trying to get Craft running

Tags: install, server

Trying to get my Craft site running on my server for the first time.

Getting the error `Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/dev.mysite.com/htdocs/public/index.php`

However, there is nothing different to the folder structure on my server than I have locally. 
i.e. the `$craftPath` set in index.php is still `../craft` which is correct... my Craft folder sits beside my public folder as per default installation.

What can I try to get this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

9 times out of 10, if you're absolutely sure the path is correct, it's either a permissions issue (PHP doesn't have permissions to open the `craft` folder) or your php.ini file has  [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restrictions in place preventing PHP from accessing the folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks Brad. Will double check these things.

Comment: It's not open_basedir... just checked php.ini and it's commented out. How would I ensure or check if php has permissions to open the craft folder?

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder and who's the user:group owner?

Comment: Looks like 775 permission on the folder.. and I'm the owner https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3a47rq1jniszcd/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2014.59.13.png?dl=0

Comment: What's the user:group Apache is running as? http://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

Comment: Ran this `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and got this -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n0h35jsp61t8ob/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2015.06.23.png?dl=0. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me but if you can make anything out that would be great. Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: When I run `ps axo user,group,comm | grep apache` I get this https://www.dropbox.com/s/oj7ioyr36plxz6b/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2015.10.08.png?dl=0. So looks like it's running as `root`.. right?

Comment: Hrm... looks like it's running as www-data. If you chance the permissions of the craft folder to 777 and it starts working, then that means www-data doesn't have write permissions. You can chmod -R www-data:www-data the craft folder and you should still be able to run with 775.

Comment: Yep.. that's it. Got it working running `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data htdocs`. Thanks for your help man!

Comment: No problem! Now all you have to do is mark this as the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

If your permissions are set correctly, your php.ini is all correct, your craft folder exists and everything seems like it should work fine... Make sure you have the `app` folder inside the `craft` folder as well.

You'll get the "Could not find your craft/ folder." if there is no app folder.

Comment: This second remark. If you are deploying with git (like I am, on Forge) of course this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the proper permissions for the Craft install via:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Then, set the correct permissions on the document root and Craft files and directories within:

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

chmod -R 770 /var/www

chmod -R 775 /var/www/craft

chmod -R 775 /var/www/html

chmod 774 /var/www/craft/app

chmod 774 /var/www/craft/config

chmod 774 /var/www/craft/storage